# Prettier.js Method Arguments on newline formatting

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I'm running Prettier.js (VSCode plugin)/`prettier-eslint-cli`.  It formats method arguments that go over the 80 character limit as the following (putting each argument on a new line).

```
someMethod(
  argumentOne,
  argumentTwo,
  argumentThree,
  argumentFour,
  argumentFive, // Hits 80 character word wrap here
  argumentSix,
  argumentSeven
) {
  // Some codes
}
```

Is there a way to modify the options so it formats the arguments to try to fit 80 characters on each row? Instead of just adding them to a new line each time.

```
someMethod(argumentOne, argumentTwo, argumentThree, argumentFour,
  argumentFive, argumentSix, argumentSeven) {
  // Some codes
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look very customizable: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html. Also in its description: "Prettier is an **opinionated** code formatter"

Comment: Yeah I've seen that.  But I know there are some commands (that they obviously list) that can be overridden.

Comment: If this is just a problem in one file, you can put a .prettierignore file in your root, and write the file path (like w/ a .gitignore) to ignore that file

Comment: Just add `// prettier-ignore` before the function.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, for now, there isn't an option for doing so. When your arguments get over the printWidth ( default 80), prettier will break each argument into a separate line.

One way could be to increase the printWidth option so that your arguments stay on the same line. The prettier documentation mentions `maximum line length rules are often set to 100 or 120` (https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

Answer (score 11):

- In `User Settings` for Prettier:

  - Set `Print Width` option to `100` or more

Answer (score 10):

Right click in the VSC window and select "command palette".
Search "prettier" and select "create configuration file",
its will open u select folder window (select the folder u want to save the prettier configuration file in),
then open the configuration file and add the options you want to change .
Example:

```
{
    "printWidth": 150
}
```

Comment: Might depend on the prettier version, but this one should probably be an integer instead (So `"printWidth":150`). Otherwise you will get `Invalid printWidth value. Expected an integer, but received "150".`