# What Prettier setting do I need to prevent line space removal before an anonymous function?

Tags: node.js, module, whitespace, code-formatting, prettier

Looking for a way in a *.prettierrc* file to prevent line space removal before an anonymous function, example before save:

```
export const a = file => {}

export const b = file => {}

;(async () => {
  console.log('foobar')
})()
```

and after save:

```
export const a = file => {}

export const b = file => {}
;(async () => {
  console.log('foobar')
})()
```

### Research

- [Prettier: Add space between function and parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265230/prettier-add-space-between-function-and-parenthesis)
- [Prettier.js Method Arguments on newline formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565587/prettier-js-method-arguments-on-newline-formatting)
- [Why doesn't prettier allow me to break the function arguments into multiline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558680/why-doesnt-prettier-allow-me-to-break-the-function-arguments-into-multiline)

In a *.prettierrc* file, how can I prevent the line removal before an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late, but essentially you can't. Prettier is an [opinionated formatter](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html), which means you won't be able to have the level of customization you're looking for in this situation.

You could try using [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) or [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), which even though it's a linter (and not a formatter), it can be used as such.

That being said, I wouldn't worry about this too much. The aim of formatters should be to keep a code style consistent, especially when collaborating with other developers. That's why most popular formatters are opinionated. No one wants to be in a team having meaningless discussions about code style :).